# Using Terraform Unable to authenticate my app via vs code

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

Using Terraform Unable to authenticate my app via vs code even after giving the right subscription ID, tenant ID, client ID and client secret getting below 401 error

building account: getting authenticated object ID: Error listing Service Principals: autorest.DetailedError{Original:adal.tokenRefreshError{message:"adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '401'. Response body: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000222: The provided client secret keys for app '7b1fda96-01aa-4910-ba98-2d5286c1c29d' are expired. Visit the Azure portal to create new keys for your app: https://aka.ms/NewClientSecret, or consider using certificate credentials for added security: [https://aka.ms/certCreds.\\r\\nTrace](https://aka.ms/certCreds.%5C%5Cr%5C%5CnTrace) ID: b056db1f-4bbe-4f3d-a32c-85cf15567800\r\nCorrelation ID: 4b925f8a-9674-455b-91f3-81b7468ca4f9\r\nTimestamp: 2022-03-08 13:22:45Z","error_codes":[7000222],"timestamp":"2022-03-08 13:22:45Z","trace_id":"b056db1f-4bbe-4f3d-a32c-85cf15567800","correlation_id":"4b925f8a-9674-455b-91f3-81b7468ca4f9","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000222"} Endpoint [https://login.microsoftonline.com/cf626e3e-0aa9-4d45-bb03-cc1e22523cf8/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0"](https://login.microsoftonline.com/cf626e3e-0aa9-4d45-bb03-cc1e22523cf8/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0%22), resp:(*http.Response)(0x1ae3e960)}, PackageType:"azure.BearerAuthorizer", Method:"WithAuthorization", StatusCode:401, Message:"Failed to refresh the Token for request to [https://graph.windows.net/cf626e3e-0aa9-4d45-bb03-cc1e22523cf8/servicePrincipals?%24filter=appId+eq+%277b1fda96-01aa-4910-ba98-2d5286c1c29d%27&api-version=1.6"](https://graph.windows.net/cf626e3e-0aa9-4d45-bb03-cc1e22523cf8/servicePrincipals?%24filter=appId+eq+%277b1fda96-01aa-4910-ba98-2d5286c1c29d%27&api-version=1.6%22), ServiceError:[]uint8(nil), Response:(*http.Response)(0x1ae3e960)}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing what the error message suggests?

> The provided client secret keys for app '7b1fda96-01aa-4910-ba98-2d5286c1c29d' are expired. Visit the Azure portal to create new keys for your app

Comment: yes tried it for n no of time just after creation of client secret using it but getting same error